# How to Design my data model in django with many OneToMany relations

Tags: python, django, database-design, django-models

I have an entity in my application which has some attribute like **auth.User** but it has also some extra attributes. So I created a OneToOne relationship with **auth.User**

```
  class UserEntity(models.Model):
     user = models.OneToOneField(User)
     ... other fields ...
```

I also have a Person model which is **UserEntity** so created it as this:

```
    class Person (models.Model):
       userEntity = models.OneToOneField(UserEntity)
       ... other fields ...
```

There are many different attributes like addresses,experiences,education and other details that I want to associate with my Person. A **Person** can have many addresses,experiences,education,speciality
I have a Speciality Model like this.

```
     class Speciality(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()
        code = models.CharField()
        ... other fields ...
```

The problem is how should I my data model be designed so that I can retrieve a person/user with all addresses,expereiences,specialities etc. I can associate each Person/user with Speciality since Speciality is an independent model and can exist without a user. Currently I have created another model for each e.g for Speciality I have created

```
         class PersonSpeciality(models.Model):
            person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
            specialities = models.ForeignKey(Speciality)
```

Can I design it in a better way so I can have fast searching and retrievals and no mess.

Thank you

Comment: why do you need to separate UserEntity from Person? Can't they be one model only?

Comment: why do you need the PersonSpeciality model for associating specialities to a Person? Just associate Speciality to Person, as well as Adress, Education, etc via normal foreign keys. Briefly: why do you need to model the association?

Comment: @Pynchia Actually I have other UserEntity models as well. Person is just one of them. Secondly the Speciality model will store different specialities which are not connected to a particular person. So I am creating PersonSpeciality to relate them.

Answer (score 1):

If a Person can have multiple Specialities, then you can implement a oneToMany relationship, just by adding a foreignKey:

```
 class Speciality(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    code = models.CharField()
    person =  models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

However, if you have several Persons with the same specialities (let's say 10 Persons are Painters), you would have 10 different Painters entries.

To avoid duplication, you can implement a ManyToMany relationship :

```
 class Speciality(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    code = models.CharField()
    person =  models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

Django will create a third table in your DB to handle that (you don't need to write your PersonSpeciality class).

Comment: Thank you for your response. But like I said in the question, Speciality is an independent model. Dont you think it's not a good idea to have person references dangling in Speciality model. The speciality has name,code and description fields which will contain different detail about each speciality?

Comment: hmmm no I don't think there is any design issue in adding a Person reference in your Speciality model. I mean, you DO have some relationship between the two models, I don't see which principle would prevent you from coding it in the Speciality model. Your PersonSpeciality class somewhat remove the relationship from the model, but to mean it i) add complexity, ii) somewhat hide a relationship that exists

Comment: Ok Can I create ManyToMany relationship in Person model? that way Speciality can exist separately. Will that still work right? like I would have different specialities for each Person